# C++ What does size parameter in qsort do

Tags: c

In qsort:

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size, int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

Documentation explains:

```
size
Size in bytes of each element in the array.
size_t is an unsigned integral type.
```

But usually qsort is invoked as `qsort(...,...,sizeof(int),...)`, or `qsort(...,...,sizeof(char *),...)`

If I am understanding correctly, since size of string can not be determined, so it does not matter anymore, instead use sizeof(char*) as a type declaration.

Any explanations?

Comment: You give `qsort()` a contiguous memory buffer containing the "items" you want to sort. The size parameter is the type-width, in bytes, of the item-type contained within that buffer. Typically it is `sizeof(type)`, where `type` is the base type of the array. Ex: sorting an `int arr[10];` would pass `10` for the number of items, and `sizeof(int)` for the size-parameter. `qsort()` uses these two numbers to know how to move from item to item in an otherwise-untyped (`void *`) memory buffer.

Comment: Further, using your example, sorting an array of char pointers, `char *ar[10]`, yes, you would use `sizeof(char*)` as the size parameter, and in this case, `10` as the `num` parameter. The most confusing thing for most people regarding `qsort()` is the comparator being called with the *addresses* within the supplied buffer of each item. In the case of an `int ar[]`, it would be an `int *`, but in the case of a container holding pointer types, `char *ar[]`, it is the *addresses* of pointers, or a `char **`. This can be a little unnerving for some not intimate with pointers-to-pointers.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Sounds like an answer to me.

Answer (score 3):

`qsort` requires a contiguous block of memory that can be treated as an array. Becaue of that, each item in the array must be the same size, and you provide that size to `qsort` when you call it.

If you want to store the actual *strings* in the array, they'll need to be all the same size, the size of the largest one.

And, when your comparison function compares them, `qsort` will almost certainly move around massive amounts of memory to complete the sort, since it will swap the strings themselves.

Far more usual is to have the strings themselves stored *outside* of the array area and just use the array to store *pointers* to those strings. The pointers themselves will be swapped but they're going to be much smaller on average than the strings they point at.

For example, with:

```
char *strings[] = {"xyzzy", "zorkmid", "twisty little passages", "plugh"};
```

the `strings` array consists of four pointers to those strings, each pointer taking up four bytes (on my system, yours may be different). When `qsort` sorts the array, the only things moved around within that array are the *pointers.*